# Flask responsive flash messages

Tags: jquery, flask, jinja2

I'm running a Flask app and trying to get flashed messages to the frontend without reloading the page. The alert is in a partial html file _flashes.html and should be loaded to a div with a jQuery script. However, no messages appear. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better solution?

### Flask

Flask needs to render the template because _flashes.html contains Jinja2 syntax.

```
@app.route("/get-flashes")
def get_flashes():
    return render_template("_flashes.html")
```

### jQuery

The html page contains the Jinja2 generated *get_flashes* URL in a meta tag: `<meta id="base-url-data" data-url-flashes="{{ url_for('get_flashes') }}">`, I can verify this works. The page also contains an empty div in the body where the jQuery script can load the partial page to: `<div id="flash-messages"></div>`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#flash-messages").load($("#base-url-data").data("url-flashes"));
    }, 2000);
});
```

### _flashes.html

```
{% for category, message in get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
<div class="alert alert-{{ category }} alert-dismissible">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <strong>{{ category }}!</strong>  {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is the browser hitting the correct URL? Does `get_flashed_messages()` return what you expect it to? E.g. if it returns an empty list your HTML snippet will be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried adding a flash message in the Flask route for the partial html and this message did load correctly in the page!

```
@app.route("/get-flashes")
def get_flashes():
    flash("hello?", "info")
    return render_template("_flashes.html")
```

The other flash messages didn't render because the code used in _flashes.html was also in the html page, but commented out. For Jinja2 it doesn't matter `get_flashed_messages` is commented out. When rendering the page, the message store is consumed and the messages disappear in the html comments.